# ios table view rows not showing up

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I create a master-detail table view using xcode 6.0, rows are added after parsing a json file (using DataManager in this case), but somehow rows are not showing up immediately. I have to scroll the simulator screen to get it updated. After a while, I figured that this problem only happens if I update my row in the `success` callback logic. Here's the table view class and datasource logic:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var objects = [AppModel]()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromFileWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in
        // I removed json parsing logic to highlight the issue
        self.objects.append(AppModel(id:1, name: "candy crush"]))
        self.insertRows()
    }

    func insertRows() {
        var index_path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([index_path], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = object.description
        return cell
    }

}
```

And here's the code for DataManager:

```
class DataManager {

  class func getTopAppsDataFromFileWithSuccess(success: ((data: NSData) -> Void)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
      let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TopApps",ofType:"json")

      var readError:NSError?
      if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!,
        options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached,
        error:&readError) {
        success(data: data)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

So if I move `self.objects.append()` and `self.insertRows()` out of `DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromFileWithSuccess`, things works perfectly. Am I missing something dealing with this async file load operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an async operation. That means it'll likely occur on a background thread, and UI can't be updated via background threads. Just add a dispatch to the main thread in your success block.

```
  self.objects.append(AppModel(id:1, name: "candy crush"]))

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
     self.insertRows()
  })
```